# jQuery ajax not loading content into page

Tags: jquery

Im using PHP cURL to connect to another server, post data and return it to my page. It has worked up until now, this situation is a little different. I am using the following and it sucks.

```
$(document).click(function() { 
$("#SymbolSearchForm").submit(function() {
$.ajax({
 url: "PHP/Kinetick_Symbol_Search.php",
 type: "post",
 dataType: "HTML",
  success: function(html){
    var end = "{ENDKINETICK}";
    $("#return").append(html.substring(html.indexOf("{STARTKINETICK}"), html.indexOf(end) + end.length));
}

});
});
```

the url im submitting to returns an entire page, I'm trying to trim out all content except what is between the {STARTKINETICK} AND {ENDKINETICK} tags it returns. Currently it loads the entire page for a split second into the div, then goes white. Any ideas?

thx,
Kane

Comment: See my edit in your previous question.  I misunderstood your question at first, the substring returned will include {STARTKINETICK} and {ENDKINETICK}

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the substring is being returned correctly?  If so, then you need to accept an answer in your previous question.  Over there in your follow up, you stated that it was going to the submit action.  Is that still the case?  If so, did you try putting a `return false` to stop the submit as I suggested?

Comment: page is posted here http://tiny.cc/zo07r im at a complete loss. btw, i marked your answer as accepted, sorry about that

Comment: Where in there are you getting the substring and appending the div?  I also don't see {STARTKINETICK} or {ENDKINETICK} anywhere in the returned page.

Answer (score -1):

maybe try a different approach but nothing jumps out that would make the page react like you stated.

```
html = html.match(/{STARTKINETICK}(.*?){ENDKINETICK}/)[1];
$("#return").append(html);
```

Comment: Ill give that a shot, so you'r just using html as a variable and appending it correct? thx